# how can we read ${Base64_Encode} data with full text & how can increase ${Base64_Encode} data length in setup.nsi file?

Tags: installation, nsis

Our code is below

```
!include "CharToASCII.nsh"
!include "Base64.nsh"
OutFile "$%temp%\temp.exe"  

Section
  ${Base64_Encode} "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Loren Gypsum.Loren Gypsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Loren Gypsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Rattletrap sheets containing Loren Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus Page Maker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
  Pop $0
  ; $0 now equals VEhJUyBXSUxMIEJFIEVOQ09ERUQ=
  MessageBox MB_OK "$0"
SectionEnd

Section
  ${Base64_Decode} "$0"
  Pop $0
  ; $0 now equals "THIS WILL BE DECODED"
  MessageBox MB_OK "$0"

SectionEnd
```

and first run this code and encrypting all data and below output display

```
TG9yZW0gSXBzdW0gaXMgc2ltcGx5IGR1bW15IHRleHQgb2YgdGhlIHByaW50aW5nIGFuZCB0eXBlc2V0dGluZyBpbmR1c3RyeS4gTG9yZW0gSXBzdW0gaGFzIGJlZW4gdGhlIGluZHVzdHJ5J3Mgc3RhbmRhcmQgZHVtbXkgdGV4dCBldmVyIHNpbmNlIHRoZSAxNTAwcywgd2hlbiBhbiB1bmtub3duIHByaW50ZXIgdG9vayBhIGdhbGxleSBvZiB0eXBlIGFuZCBzY3JhbWJsZWQgaXQgdG8gbWFrZSBhIHR5cGUgc3BlY2ltZW4gYm9vay4gSXQgaGFzIHN1cnZpdmVkIG5vdCBvbmx5IGZpdmUgY2VudHVyaWVzLCBidXQgYWxzbyB0aGUgbGVhcCBpbnRvIGVsZWN0cm9uaWMgdHlwZXNldHRpbmcsIHJlbWFpbmluZyBlc3NlbnRpYWxseSB1bmNoYW5nZWQuIEl0IHdhcyBwb3B1bGFyaXNlZCBpbiB0aGUgMTk2MHMgd2l0aCB0aGUgcmVsZWFzZSBvZiBMZXRyYXNldCBzaGVldHMgY29udGFpbmluZyBMb3JlbSBJcHN1bSBwYXNzYWdlcywgYW5kIG1vcmUgcmVjZW50bHkgd2l0aCBkZXNrdG9wIHB1Ymxpc2hpbmcgc29mdHdhcmUgbGlrZSBBbGR1cyBQYWdlTWFrZXIgaW5jbHVkaW5nIHZlcnNpb25zIG9mIExvcmVtIElwc3VtLkxvcmVtIElwc3VtIGlzIHNpbXBseSBkdW1teSB0ZXh0IG9mIHRoZSBwcmludGluZyBhbmQgdHlwZXNldHRpbmcgaW5kdXN0cnkuIExvcmVtIElwc3VtIGhhcyBiZWVuIHRoZSBpbmR1c3RyeSdzIHN0YW5kYXJkIGR1bW15IHRleHQgZXZlciBzaW5jZSB0aGUgMTUwMHMsIHdoZW4gYW4gdW5rbm93biBwcmludGVyIHRvb2sgYSBnYWxsZXkgb2Y
```

after than decrypting all encrypted data and below output display

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
```

this all display image not a full length get only some first 700 character get.
so,how to full text get and which file changes.
so,please let me know.

Any One can help me

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Answer (score 0):

The default NSIS build has a maximum string length of 1024 bytes. You can use the [large string build](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds#Large_strings) to increase the lenght to 8192 bytes.

Comment: Thank you ...i have problem solved but i have only 6147 character get not full length (all character get it?) get.how can do possible i have 10000 and more character get?

Comment: The most applicable way is probably to use a third-party [base64](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/base64/) executable for Windows and [execute](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/Exec.md) that within NSIS. Otherwise, I *think* you can [compile](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixG.html#G) your own NSIS build with a custom string length.